# MYSQL , PHP select from database shows broken images

Tags: php, mysql, select, blob

i have been trying this for a few hours now and still no luck. Once the image has been inserted to the database but when i come to "SELECT" from database all the images are "Broken" . Im using 2 files, getimage.php and the file where i want all the images to appear.

View All Images

```
//Connecting Is Here
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM animals LIMIT 50";
$res = mysql_query($SQL);
$numRows = mysql_numrows($res);
$i =0;
while($i < $numRows){
    ?>
    <table width="600" class="blue">
        <tr>
            <td class="blue">
                <p class="white"><?php echo $_GET['ImageId']?><p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="lightblue">
                <br>
                <div align="center">
                    <img width="550" src="getimage.php?ImageId=<?php echo mysql_result($res, $i, "ImageId"); ?>"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

GetImage.php

```
if (IsSet($_GET['ImageId'])){
     $gotten = mysql_query("SELECT  `Image` FROM  `animals` WHERE  `ImageId` LIMIT 0 , 30 = ".$_GET['ImageId']);
     header("Content-type: image/jpg");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($gotten))
     {
        print $row['image'];
     }
     mysql_free_result($gotten);
  }
?>
```

Comment: r u getting the image url correctly in view all images php file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
<img width="550" src="getimage.php?ImageId=<?php echo mysql_result($res,$i,"ImageId"); ?       >  "/>
```

into this:

```
<img width="550" src="getimage.php?ImageId=<?php echo mysql_result($res,$i,$_GET[ImageId]); ?       >  "/>
```

Comment: Let me see what's the DB looks like.

Comment: CREATE TABLE example
(
ImageId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Image LONGBLOB,
PRIMARY KEY(ImageId)
);

Comment: It seems you don't need a $_GET['ImageId']. You get that value from a url but doing nothing with database. What are you going to do here? Are you going to get the image according to the value from $_GET['ImageId'] or just loop calling the image from mysql?

Comment: Well im trying to display every image in the database in one page.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to display all images in one page. You don't need to get the ImageId from url. Just fetch it directly from your DB. Just like this:

```
$gotten = mysql_query("SELECT  'Image' FROM  'animals' LIMIT 0 , 30");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($gotten)){
  print "<img src=\"../images/$row['image']\" />;
}
```